# Scope in C programming (Global and local variable)

Tags: c, scope

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int i = 3; 
    printf("%d\n", i);
    if (i == 3) {
        i = i + 1;
        int i = 6; 
        printf("%d\n", i);
        i = i + 1;
    }

    if (i == 3) {
        printf("%d\n", i); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My Question is Why the 4 and 7 disappear?

When I run the code they only print the output 3 and 6 ?

Comment: The first `i = i + 1` increments the outer `i`, so the second `if` is never entered.

Comment: Which line you expect should print 7? Maybe you missed one more `printf("%d\n", i);` after second `i = i + 1;`?

Comment: You only have three printfs so you can't expect four numbers to be printed. And it's YOUR code, YOU can debug it. Hint: use a debugger!

Comment: Probably you have warning messages from the compiler - don't ignore them!

Answer (score 9):

Nothing here *"disappears"*, this happens because, the inner scope takes precedence over the outer scope for identifiers with overlapping scope.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.2.1 (*emphasis mine*)

> [...] If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name
>   space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the scope of one entity (the inner scope) will end
>   strictly before the scope of the other entity (the outer scope). **Within the inner scope, the
>   identifier designates the entity declared in the inner scope; the entity declared in the outer
>   scope is hidden (and not visible) within the inner scope.**

So, in your case, (*follow the comments*)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {   //note the correct signature
    int i = 3;            //outer scope of i
    printf("%d\n", i);
    if (i == 3) {
        i = i + 1;         //this happens in "outer" scope, i value changed...
        //--------------------->     |-----inner scope starts, outer scope gets hidden
        int i = 6;                // |
        printf("%d\n", i);        // |
        i = i + 1;                // |
    }//------------------------>     |-----inner scope ends, outer scope resumes

    if (i == 3) {                 // hey. look , other scope is back!!!
        printf("%d\n", i); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OMG THANK YOU, now i know where is the wrong haha and finally understand~ but why the "Other scope" cannot output the number of 3 ?    Cus the "Other Scope" now is outer scope already right ? so it should print 3 ?

Comment: int main () and int main (void) are different ? void means nothing right ?

Comment: @ThomasLeong it outputs `3`, as you said...`3` (from outer) and `6` (from inner), right?

Comment: @ThomasLeong no, they are not the same, at least not in this case. `()` means no constraint on number/type of args, but `(void)` means explicitly none.

Comment: Now lets say the code have 3 printf.   The First print output 3,  the second print output 6, and the Third print nothing ? @@

Answer (score 1):

The output is so because the local variables have a greater preference over the global variables or variables declared not in the same scope. Each time you initialize an existing variable with a value in a scope, the value becomes dominant in its scope. This similar situation in java is referred to as "Namespace Collision".
It is to be noted here that the c complier allows auto storage class as default storage class which allows you to initialize again.I am referring to int i=6. However, using static storage class won't allow you to initialize the same variable again !